# I find duplicated class in firebase library . How to exclude?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I find duplicated classes in one of this 3 lib of firebase:

```
 com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4

 com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.0.0

 com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.3
```

I want to exclude or similar like this, I don't want to use multidex cuz i want my app to install in devices 4.0.3 and up.

Before that, I had old version of this lib

```
com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.1
```

And i had no problem but this old version of this library doesn't show ads.

Comment: you don't. Those classes will be used by other classes, remove them and they will break

Comment: Mixing major versions 17 and 16 looks suspicious. Are you sure this is correct?

Comment: @Henry in android studio notify me that latest ver of lib is 17.+

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude that particular class from your import:

```
compile('com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4') {
      exclude module: 'abcxyz'
}
```

Comment: Shivam Yadav can u help to find that dublicated class how to ?

Comment: The class name will be displayed in the exception which you are getting, you can simply copy from there and use it.